# Generating same numbers in array of Objects

Tags: python

Ive got problem with generating same numbers in my code im not using any seed and evry, the object is created in the loop it has same numbers inside array.

```
class Car:
    genome = list()

    def __init__(self, genome = None):


        self.createGenome()
        print(self.genome)

    def createGenome(self):
        for x in range(genomeLength):
            #if len(self.genome) < 500:
            #    self.genome.append(random.randint(0, 6))
            number = randomNumber()
            self.genome.append(randomNumber())

class GenerationOfCars:
    count = 50
    generation = list()

    def __init__(self):
        self.createGeneration()
        #print(self.generation)

    def createGeneration(self):
        for x in range(self.count):
            car = Car()
            self.generation.append(car)
            print(x)
def randomNumber():
    return randint(1,10)
generation = GenerationOfCars()
singlePointCrossover(generation.generation[0], generation.generation[1])
print(generation.generation)
```

im trying to make 50 cars with unique random instructions but its still same for every car. But the objects created and appended into list are not the same.

Comment: `genome` is a *class attribute* of `Car`, NOT an instance attribute.  Every `Car` that you create will share that one list.  You need to create the list in `__init__()` if you want it to be different for each instance.

Comment: You'll also notice that the length of genome is count * genomeLength, rather than just genomeLength.  As @jasonharper notes, everything is being added to a single list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @jasonharper already mentioned your problem is that `genome` is a class attribute. It is the same list for all of your cars. To make it worse, each car creation extends the list with `genomeLength` number of random values.

Move `self.genome = self.createGenome()` to the `__init__()` and it should be done.